# Exists a way to configure capistrano 3 to use a git repository via ssh with username / password authentication?

Tags: git, capistrano, capistrano3

Well.. I'm not saying it's a great a idea.. but it can be done?

```
01 git ls-remote --heads ssh://git@host/srv/git/repo.git
      01 Permission denied (publickey,password).
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
```

I know it was possible with Capistrano 2; tried set :scm_username and :scm_password but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way this can be done as stated.

Public/Private key auth works, and you can use username/password with https.

You might be able to hack something together with `~/.ssh/config` on the server to pass the ssh command through a proxy command which injects the password, kind of like https://askubuntu.com/a/634789.